# PowerBI Connector Issue

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to connect the forge hub with the help of the beta version of Forge - PowerBI connection recently shared by the Autodesk Team.

I am getting the below error when I click on connect button.
[Forge Model/data Connector to Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmhOL.png)

[Error message after clicking on connect button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XUIf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you missed to add the client id of this application (connector) to your BIM account.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/endymion/v1/developers_guide/exporting_bim360/
if you are not the BIM account administrator, you will need to ask the admin to add this integration with the steps above.

Comment: I have added a custom integration by following the above steps.

Even I am getting the above error message.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: sorry for my late response. we can have a quick call to diagnose. Please send me email at xiaodong.liang At autodesk.com to book the time.

Comment: I have diagnosed the issue, and it is fixed now. I have another concern. How do get extract all parameters from the BIM model, such as shared parameters and so on?

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: update: by direct email, Ravi has discussed with my colleague Petr about related questions