# PowerBI Forge/B360 Connector Issue

Tags: powerbi, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to insert my model into Power BI using the Autodesk API, but I'm facing some difficulties. Here is the page that details what I want to do: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/endymion/v1/developers_guide/setup/

I'm encountering the same issue as in this question:
[PowerBI Connector Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76428761/powerbi-connector-issue)
So, I followed the steps of the solution, but the problem persists.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The Endymion program has been deprecated. We have opened the source of Power BI card of APS Viewer. Please check the new sample at https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-powerbi-tools